# Executing bash code interactively using -c flag (With |& and gnu screen)

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

*Before we get into the weeds: I'm choosing to use `screen` as a very crude multithreading tool. This is because I like `screen`, it's everywhere I care about, and it suits this purpose.*

I'm trying to have screen run `get_fileserver_file_from_api`, and redirect stderr + stdout to both the screen session as well as a text file.

The command I *would like* is

```
screen -dmS <generated_session_id> bash -c './get_fileserver_file_from_api <file_uri> -f "<save_directory>" |& tee -a "<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt"'
```

Currently, I can't figure out how to redirect the output from `get_fileserver_file_from_api` into `<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt`.

I've tried

---

```sh
screen -dmS <generated_session_id> bash -c './get_fileserver_file_from_api <file_uri> -f "<save_directory>" |& tee -a "<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt"'
```

Which gives `` bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&' ``

---

```sh
screen -dmS <generated_session_id> bash -c './get_fileserver_file_from_api <file_uri> -f "<save_directory>"' |& tee -a "<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt"
```

Which runs the command successfully, but does not save `get_fileserver_file_from_api`'s output to `downloadlog.txt`. (Seems  to output `screen`'s output)

---

```sh
screen -dmS <generated_session_id> bash -c './get_fileserver_file_from_api <file_uri> -f "<save_directory>" \|& tee -a "<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt"'
```

Which acts odd and *also* doesn't output to `downloadlog.txt`

---

```sh
screen -dmS <generated_session_id> bash -c './get_fileserver_file_from_api <file_uri> -f "<save_directory>" \|\& tee -a "<save_directory>/downloadlog.txt"'
```

Which simply passes everything as an argument for `get_fileserver_file_from_api` (which then fails as it doesn't have an `-a` option)

---

Etc

---

Either `bash` directly tells me I have bad syntax or the `downloadlog.txt` is not correct.

I'm sure this is a problem with escaping properly, but I just can't seem to unlock it without help.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `|&`. It's [highly discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Just `2>&1 |`

Comment: Please make sure your command works outside of `screen`. `|&` is a Bash4+ feature, so if you're e.g. running on macOS it'll fail regardless of escaping

Comment: Awesome, thank you both of you. I didn't run across anything steering me away from |&, but @thatotherguy you hit the nail on the head: this is on macOS.

Comment: @KamilCuk: If you like, you can add that comment as an answer and I will mark it as my solution. (It did in-fact work exactly as I was hoping)